# PMA Rudin Theorem 7.26: Change of variable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

[image]

[image]

After $(51)$, Rudin changes the variable

$P_n(x) = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt$  $\to$  $P_n(x) = \int_{-x}^{1-x} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt$

How does he change it?

---

Update: Now I know It's not the change of variable

And I know that $f(x) = 0$ except $x \in [0,1]$, but I want to give a rigorous process to convince me $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt = \int_{-x}^{1-x} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt$$

---

Update: Equivalent to prove $$\int_{-1}^{-x} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt + \int_{1-x}^{1} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt = 0 $$
Proof : $x+t \in [x-1,0]$ in the first integral, $x+t \in [1,x+1]$ in the second, because $x \in [0,1]$, so both of these $x+t$ outside of $[0,1]$, so both of integrals are $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a change of variable. It’s the next equality that is. Here it is just the fact that $f$ is $0$ outside $[0,1]$, so $f(x+t)=0$ unless $t\in [-x,1-x]$.

Comment: Hello, you can see my new update!

Comment: I addressed this. To put it another way, what interval is obtained when you translate $[0,1]$ $t$ units to the left?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I switched $x$ and $t$ in this whole discussion; I shouldn’t answer typing on my phone. We’re integrating with respect to $t$, so we translate $x$ units.

Comment: $[-t, 1-t]$, what's the next step?

Comment: OK, that's $[-x, 1-x]$, but I still cannot obviously see that $$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt = \int_{-x}^{1-x} f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt$$

Comment: Did you read what Rudin said and what I repeated? $f(u) = 0$ whenever $u\notin [0,1]$. So $f(x+t)=0$ whenever $x+t\notin [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, I've read it, but I don't know why you think this equation is then obvious ......

Comment: I've also written a proof but by the difference of two of these integrals.

Comment: To be blunt: You should not be trying to read Rudin if the following is not obvious to you. If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin (a,b)$, then $\int_A^B f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ whenever $A\le a<b\le B$. Yes, if $f$ is identically zero on an interval, then its integral over that interval is indeed zero.

Comment: OK, I think I get your meaning, -1 to 1 integral, it's what your B to A integral is, and -x to 1-x integral, it's what your b to a integral is.